# Can't open PowerShell with administrative rights

Tags: windows, powershell, administrator

I'm running Windows 10 and a few weeks ago I managed to do something (in the middle of the night - can't remember) such that I can't open PowerShell (nor PowerShell ISE) with administrative rights anymore. When opening it via right-click -> as admin, the Shell opens and closes immediately. Opening without administrative rights works fine.

I managed to find the error through opening a `cmd` as admin and typing the command "PowerShell". It says (translated):

"The type initializer for "System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace" caused an exception"

Google seems not to come up with similar cases. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it just your Powershell, or other apps as well? You should run a `sfc /scannow`

Comment: If nothing helps: re-install.

Comment: Can you open CMD with admin rights? What happens when you start PowerShell from there? Also try [without profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles)

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Just PowerShell. Ran the command and it said that it found corrupted files and repaired them. In the log file are numerous entries of the form: "Error: Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory \??\C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\.." 
I restarted the PC and still can't open it.

Comment: @marsze Re-install aborts because it can't find %ProgramFiles%. Finds it in explorer, though. Tampered with it (changed it to D:\ for disc space etc.), but changed it back to "C:\Program Files", and it still aborts (in the "computing space requirements" step)

Comment: @iRon Yes, I can, and I tried to start it from there. That's how I found the error. Now tried "PowerShell -NoProfile", same error.

Comment: Reinstall the dotnet frame pkg

Comment: Update: Managed to install the newest version separately through the ZIP file. Just leaving the rest as is. Thanks.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala re-installed the .NET frame package and now I can't open my calculator anymore, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was, that I had changed the registry entries in "\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" to "%ProgramFiles%" a while ago, in an attempt to change the default location of new programs to whichever path I defined in the environment variable. Now I hardcoded it to my new desired location (on D:). I can open the PowerShell as admin again.

Answer (score 0):

you could Try the new PowerShell Core it can do everything the normal powershell can do too
and its opensource :)
[PowerShell Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: I installed it into a new folder through the ZIP and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Update: It seems it can't do everything the normal powershell can do.. it doesn't know the command "get-appxpackage". Any suggestions?

Comment: Yea there is a 

[issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues?q=get-appxpackage) 

with that. Try this `import-module appx -usewindowspowershell`